# issue iterating a python string list

Tags: python, string, list

Hello I'm getting an issue while I'm trying to remove every len of string in the list that is mod by 2

```py
def remove_even_length(l):
    for i in l:
        if  len(i) %2==0:
            if i in l:
                l.remove(i)
    return l

wordlist = ["be", "is", "not", "or", "question", "the", "to"]
print(remove_even_length(wordlist))
```

what is happening is when it goes inside the list it skips ,[is , question] which both are mod 2 I don't know why it doesn't check the len of these 2 strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're operating on the list as you're iterating through it. Try creating a separate results list, and pushing the values that do/don't fit your criteria to this new list. I think you'll find your results then.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a problem resulting from the fact that you are iterating over the list while changing it.

Try creating a new list and returning it:

```
def remove_even_length(old_list):
    new_list = []
    for i in old_list:
        if len(i) % 2 != 0:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list


wordlist = ["be", "is", "not", "or", "question", "the", "to"]
wordlist_without_even = remove_even_length(wordlist)
print(wordlist_without_even)
```

Or just use a List Comprehension:

```
wordlist = ["be", "is", "not", "or", "question", "the", "to"]
wordlist_without_even = list([word for word in wordlist if len(word) % 2 != 0])
print(wordlist_without_even)
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are removing elements while iterating which changes the length of list while looping. You can use the following code to remove the elements based on a condition in one line.

```
def remove_even_length(l):
    l1 = [x for x in l if len(x) % 2]


    return l1
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out I must remove every even element backwards.

```py
def remove_even_length(l):
    for i in l[::-1]:
        if not (len(i) %2==1):
            l.remove(i)
    return l

wordlist = ["be", "is", "not", "or", "question", "the", "to"]
print(remove_even_length(wordlist))
```